# Default GPU after installing Ubuntu

Tags: gpu

What GPU will ubuntu use by default? if i havent installed drivers for my nvidia card?    (I have HD4000 and nvidia gt730m)

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have AMD Radeon HD4000. I have Radeon/Intel hybrid and I find method [described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) worked for Me with different Radeon HD and Intel GPUs.

Here I quote what worked for me:

3.1. Manually installing Catalyst 13.4

Before you go about installing the fglrx driver from AMD Catalyst 11.10 do read the release notes.

In this how-to an AMD64 Ubuntu 11.10/12.04 installation using a AMD Radeon HD 6300M will be chosen for illustrative purposes.

Note: Remember to uninstall the AMD proprietary fglrx graphics if it is already installed and reboot your system.   Download the drivers found at the AMD website. To avoid complications later on, save it inside an empty folder. Enable the Source Code repository in Synaptic Package Manger, then open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

On a standard desktop install of Ubuntu 10.10 you may also need to install the QT4 libraries, to do this type:

```
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4
```

On a standard desktop install of Ubuntu 12.04 you may also need to install dh-make libraries, to do this type:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-make dh-modaliases execstack libc6-i386 lib32gcc1
```

Note: This is not necessary if you are running Kubuntu or have already installed the libraries. Still using the terminal, navigate to the folder where you downloaded the drivers.

**Ubuntu 13.04 Raring:**

```
sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/raring
```

**Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS Precise:**

```
sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
```

If it is required, a package manager window will open and install some dependencies and after a while create the following three .deb packages:

```
    fglrx_12.104-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
    fglrx-amdcccle_12.104-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
    fglrx-dev_12.104-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Note: It will also create a file called fglrx-installer_12.104-0ubuntu1_amd64.changes. If you wish you can read this file to know the changes that have been effected through AMD Catalyst 13.4 and related information. To install the created .deb files, type:

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Note: In case any of the packages are broken, open Synaptic Package Manager and go to Edit -> Fix Broken Packages. In case you are new to Ubuntu, broken here means that some dependent packages are not yet installed. Once you sort out the issue as indicated above through the Synaptic Package Manager, the problem of broken packages should be resolved.

Continuing with the installation, type:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

After this command, reboot your system. If all is right, the fglrx driver that corresponds to AMD Catalyst 12.3 will be installed and working on your system. To confirm the drivers are working open a terminal and type:

```
fglrxinfo
```

You should get an output similar to the following:

```
fglrxinfo 
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6300M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Note: If you see any mention of MESA in the output, the fglrx drivers have not been installed correctly. See the troubleshooting section for more details You can make configuration changes through the AMD Catalyst Control Center, it can either be found in your Application menu or you can launch it through a terminal like this:

```
gksudo amdcccle
```

To read more about the AMD Catalyst Control Center click here. Keep in mind that all configuration options for the AMD Catalyst Control Center mentioned there may not be available for your Ubuntu system.